# Is there a way (may be an addon) to resize textures in batch inside blender?

Tags: texturing, optimization

I use asset libraries and some assets comes with ridiculously large textures for my specific scene. Imported about ten assets(grass and props) and now I have hundreds of 8k textures.  My Vram is full and renders are very very slow now. Is there a way to select and resize hundreds of textures to a certain size?

Answer (score 1):

In Properties Editor > Render settings tab > Simplify panel, there is a texture resolution setting:

[image]

> Automatically scales textures down so that they are no larger than the values chosen. This can help reduce computer memory resources when rendering large scenes with huge textures.
>
> ---
>
> **Source: [Simplify — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/render/cycles/render_settings/simplify.html?utm_source=blender-4.0.2#bpy-types-cyclesrendersettings-texture-limit)**

Comment: Does this affect all images? Can I make it not affect certain images (like background textures and textures that are close to the camera)?

Comment: It limits all textures' resolution.